# symfony2 not validating properly

Tags: php, validation, symfony

controller portion:

```
        $contact->setEmail($request->request->get('email'))
                ->setFirstName($request->request->get('firstname'))
                ->setLastName($request->request->get('lastname'))
                ->setSource($request->request->get('source'))
                ->setIpAddress($request->request->get('ipaddr'))
                ->setCreated(new \DateTime());

        $validator = $this->get('validator');
        $this->errors = $validator->validate($contact);

        $response = new Response(json_encode(
          array(
            'errors'=>$this->errors
          )
        ));
        return $response;
```

validation.yml:

```
Mailer\MainBundle\Entity\Contact:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: email
    properties:
        email:
            - Email:
                message: The email you entered is invalid
                checkMX: false
        ipAddress:
            - Ip: ~
        source:
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 50
                minMessage: Must be between 2 and 50 characters
                maxMessage: Must be between 2 and 50 characters
```

$this->errors always comes out as an empty object regardless of what is in input. validation for this same entity works in other controllers, but I am validating via the $form->isValid() method for those. This controller is for API functionality - so I cannot use that method. Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  The problem is not with the validator.  The problem is caused because json_encode doesn't handle certain objects nicely.  In this case, if you create a string or simple array of all the errors, and then return the string/array as json, it should work.

```
$messages = array();
foreach($this->errors as $error){
    $messages[] = $error->getMessage();
}
$response = new Response(json_encode(
      array(
        'errors'=>$messages
      )
));
return $response;
```

OR

```
$messages = '';
foreach($this->errors as $error){
    $messages .= $error->getMessage() . ";";
}
$response = new Response(json_encode(
      array(
        'errors'=>$messages
      )
));
return $response;
```

This is what solved my problem with json_encode.  hope it will work for you too.

EDIT:
It looks like the validator returns a resource.  json_encode cannot encode resources.  see [php docs](https://www.php.net/json_encode)